# Проблема внутри цикла for при работе с getJSON()

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться. Почему не работает код?

Задача простая: мне нужно перебрать несколько url'ов, подсовывая их в $.getJSON, затем проверить одну переменную в полученном от сервера json объекте и в зависимости от ее значения вывести результат. Код таков:

```
var chObjArr = [
        { name: 'ESL_SC2',      online: null },
        { name: 'OgamingSC2',   online: null },
        { name: 'cretetion',    online: null },
        { name: 'freecodecamp', online: null },
        { name: 'storbeck',     online: null },
        { name: 'habathcx',     online: null },
        { name: 'RobotCaleb',   online: null },
        { name: 'noobs2ninjas', online: null }        
        ];


 function myUpdateList() {
      for(var i = 0; i < chObjArr.length; i++) {    

        $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + chObjArr[i].name + '?callback=?', function(data) {

          if(data.stream) { //its online


            console.log(chObjArr[i].name + " online");

          }
          else { //offline


            console.log(chObjArr[i].name + " offline");

          }        
        });      
      }

 $(document).ready(function() {

    myUpdateList();

    });
```

1. Вопрос - почему этот код не работает? Как только я внутри if{}, else {} пытаюсь обратиться к своему массиву chObjArr, то код перестает работать и в результате ничего не выводится? Скажем, если я заменю внутри if строки:

   console.log(chObjArr[i].name + " online");

на просто:
console.log(" online ");

то все выводится в консоль и работает как надо.

2. Еще вопрос - почему аналогичный, на мой взгляд, код работает успешно? Только в нем вместо цикла for используется forEach. Это как-то связано с тем, что в случае forEach создается новый объект — итератор? Как это объяснить?

   ```
         function updateList() {
         chObjArr.forEach(function(channel) {
         $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + channel.name + '?callback=?', function(data) {

           if (data.stream) {

           // channel is online
           console.log(channel.name + ' is online');

         } else {

           // channel is offline        
           console.log(channel.name + ' is offline');

         }
       });
     });
   }
   ```

Я поискал похожие темы на форуме, но не нашел ответа конкретно на свои вопросы. Спасибо.

Comment: @Grundy-y-y! У Вас, я полагаю, ссылка на существующий вопрос находится в буфере обмена?

Comment: @Igor, нет, просто популярные вопросы иногда получается поиском искать :)

Comment: @C01 Как Вы уже поняли, дело в значении переменной `i` к моменту выполнения анонимных обработчиков, передаваемых в `$.getJSON`. Вам подойдет: `$.getJSON('...', (function(data){ console.log(this.name); }).bind(chObjArr[i]) );`.

Comment: Спасибо за полезные ответы!